# How to rename a pandas Series?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I change the name of a `Series` object?

Comment: Now-a-days, [you can call the `rename()` function if you do not want to modify your existing Series](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55295478/4909087) (for purposes such as method chaining).

Answer (score 27):

You can do this by changing the `name` attribute of your `subs` object:

Assuming its name is `'Settle'` and you want to change it to, say, `'Unsettle'`, just update the `name` attribute, like so:

```
In [16]: s = Series(randn(10), name='Settle')

In [17]: s
Out[17]:
0    0.434
1   -0.581
2   -0.263
3   -1.384
4   -0.075
5   -0.956
6    0.166
7    0.138
8   -0.770
9   -2.146
Name: Settle, dtype: float64

In [18]: s.name
Out[18]: 'Settle'

In [19]: s.name = 'Unsettle'

In [20]: s
Out[20]:
0    0.434
1   -0.581
2   -0.263
3   -1.384
4   -0.075
5   -0.956
6    0.166
7    0.138
8   -0.770
9   -2.146
Name: Unsettle, dtype: float64

In [21]: s.name
Out[21]: 'Unsettle'
```

Answer (score 15):

Not sure why no one mentioned [rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename.html)

```
s.rename("new_name", inplace=True)
```

Comment: using .rename() is the best way if you ask me, although I wouldn't use inplace=True, but rather do: series_ = series_.rename('new_name')

Comment: why not `inplace=True`?

Comment: @SandervandenOord I believe under the hood pandas does exactly that

Comment: Here's why you shouldn't use inplace=True: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59242208/3489155

Comment: `inplace=True` didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

```
s.reset_index(name="New_Name")
```

or

```
s.to_frame("New_Name")["New_Name"]
```

Comment: This converts the series to a DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

I finally renamed my **Series** object to 'Desired_Name' as follows

```
# Let my_object be the pandas.Series object
my_object.name = 'Desired_Name'
```

Then the automatically generated name that now is read in the legend now is 'Desired_Name' against 'Settle' previously.