# Pandas inplace operation in apply

Tags: python, pandas, in-place

I am expecting a strange pandas behaviour. In the following code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def info(df):
    print(f"whole df: {hex(id(df))}")
    print(f"col a   : {hex(id(df['a']))}")
    print(f"col b   : {hex(id(df['b']))}")
    print(f"col c   : {hex(id(df['c']))}")

def _drop(col):
    print(f"called on  : {col.name}")
    print(f"before drop: {hex(id(col))}")
    col[0] = -1    
    col.dropna(inplace=True)
    col[0] = 1
    print(f"after drop : {hex(id(col))}")   


df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 1.2, np.nan],
                   [5.8, np.nan, np.nan]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

info(df)
df.apply(_drop)
info(df)
```

if I comment out the `dropna()` line, or call `dropna(inplace=False)` I get a result that I expected (because `dropna` creates a copy and I am modifying the original series):

```
     a    b    c
 0  1.0  1.0  1.0
 1  5.8  NaN  NaN
```

But when `dropna(inplace=True)` the operation should be done inplace, thus modifying the original series, but the result I get is:

```
     a    b    c
 0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0
 1  5.8  NaN  NaN
```

However I would expect the result to be the same as in previous cases. Is `dropna` operation returning a clone even though the operation is inplace?
I am using pandas version 0.23.1.

**Edit:**
Based on provided answers I added `hex(ids())` calls to verify actual instances. The above code printed this (values might be different for you, but equality between them should be the same)

```
whole df   : 0x1f482392f28
col a      : 0x1f482392f60
col b      : 0x1f48452af98
col c      : 0x1f48452ada0
called on  : a
before drop: 0x1f480dcc2e8
after drop : 0x1f480dcc2e8
called on  : b
before drop: 0x1f480dcc2e8
after drop : 0x1f480dcc2e8
called on  : a
before drop: 0x1f480dcc2e8
after drop : 0x1f480dcc2e8
called on  : b
before drop: 0x1f4ffef1ef0
after drop : 0x1f4ffef1ef0
called on  : c
before drop: 0x1f480dcc2e8
after drop : 0x1f480dcc2e8
whole df   : 0x1f482392f28
col a      : 0x1f482392f60
col b      : 0x1f48452af98
col c      : 0x1f48452ada0
```

It is weird that the function is called 2 times on columns `a` and `b`, however the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) says it is called twice only on the first column.

Additionally, the hex value for the second pass of column `b` is different. Both does not happen when the `col.drop()` is omitted.

The hex values suggests that `.apply()` creates a new copy of the columns, however how it propagates the values back to the original `df` is unknown to me.

Comment: What do you *expect* as your desired output?

Comment: Please refer this Post for an understanding of inplace. [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893457/python-pandas-understanding-inplace-true)

Comment: @Mr.J: This post does not answer the author's question...

Comment: This is an interesting question - if you add an `print(hex(id(col)))` twice to the function, you can see that no copy is done

Comment: @Thomas it talks about how inplace works.

Comment: @Lukas: For me, it is called 3x on the first column... Weird behaviour indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reason through this with variable scope concepts, wouldn't consider it as a full answer but maybe it will be insightful for someone else.

When .apply executes on each series corresponding here to the col argument, inside the scope of _drop() line col[0] = -1 changes globally "first row" of the df and therefore it mutates it. When dropna() is called with inplace=True, NaNs are actually dropped but ONLY for the series inside the scope of that function, it's not assigned to the global df. Even though it overwrites the variable col. Another insight might be that Docs says that .dropna(inplace=True) returns None and _drop() also would return None since there is no return statement.

Comment: The line `col[0] = -1` does not change globally first row of the df, but only the first row in the `col` series (that is one specific element in the df). I updated my code and you can see, that the variable `col` is not modified after the drop. Lastly, I don't see any connection with the return type, both `.dropna(inplace=True)` and `_drop()` modify the object inplace, therefore they do not need a return type.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth raising this issue at the pandas / numpy github - to me, this looks like unexpected behavior - If you add a `return col` statement to the function, your code works as expected. This indicates that indeed, a local copy is created. `print(hex(id(col)))` confirms this.

```
def _drop(col):
    col[0] = -1
    col.dropna(inplace=True)
    col[0] = 1
    return col # <----

df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 1.2, np.nan],
                   [5.8, np.nan, np.nan]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

df.apply(_drop)
```

Comment: Yes this approach works, however the line `df.apply(_drop)` creates a new dataframe. The original `df` remains with -1 as in my question. That might be the reason why the id is different.

Comment: As mentioned, I recommend raising an issue on the [pandas github page](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas). Even if this is not a bug, it is definitely unexpected behavior.

Comment: If you do raise an issue there, please post the link here, I would be interested in the outcome as well.