# How to avoid Implicit fix done by python with UserWarning after Masking Data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, data-science

When I mask my set of data with another, it shows up with a UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index. How would I avoid this? Python will automatically reindex it with but the header for that column is blank and I cannot seem to rename it so I may reference that column in my code. I prefer to not rely on this implicit correction as well.

I have tried to rename the columns manually in two ways pd.DataFrame.columns() or pd.DataFrame.rename(). For some reason I either get an error that it was expecting 3 elements rather than 4 or the empty column index that was added will not be renamed.

```
# select data and filter it which results in the error which fixes the dataframe but leaves the column name empty

stickData = data[['Time','Pitch Stick Position(IN)','Roll Stick Position (IN)']]
filteredData = stickData[contactData['CONTACT'] == 1]

# moving forward from the error I tried using rename which does not error but also does nothing
filteredData.rename(index={0:'Index'})

# I also tried this
filteredData.rename(index={'':'Old_Index'})

# I even went and tried to add the names of the dataframe like so which resulted in ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 3 elements, new values have 4 elements
filteredData.columns = ['Old_Index','Time','Pitch Stick Position(IN)','Roll Stick Position (IN)']
```

The current dataframe of filteredData.head()  looks like this after the implicit correction from python:

```
Index              Time          Pitch Stick Position(IN)  Roll Stick Position (IN)
0       1421  240:19:06:40.200                  0.007263                 -0.028500
1       1422  240:19:06:40.400                  0.022327                  0.139893
2       1423  240:19:06:40.600                 -0.016409                  0.540756
3       1424  240:19:06:40.800                 -0.199329                  0.279971
4       1425  240:19:06:41.000                  0.013719                 -0.018069
```

But I would like to display with Old_index labeled and more so without relying on the implicit correction:

```
Index   Old_index   Time          Pitch Stick Position(IN)  Roll Stick Position (IN)
1       1421  240:19:06:40.200                  0.007263                 -0.028500
2       1422  240:19:06:40.400                  0.022327                  0.139893
3       1423  240:19:06:40.600                 -0.016409                  0.540756
4       1424  240:19:06:40.800                 -0.199329                  0.279971
5       1425  240:19:06:41.000                  0.013719                 -0.018069
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few errors in your code:

1. Don't use [chained indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy). Use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) / [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) accessors instead.
2. [Assign back to variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45856125/9209546) when using methods that don't operate in place.
3. In general, don't use Boolean indexers derived from *other* dataframes. If you can guarantee row alignment, then extract the NumPy array representation via [`pd.Series.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html).

For example, this would work, assuming the rows in `contactData` align with the rows in `filteredData`

```
cols = ['Time','Pitch Stick Position(IN)','Roll Stick Position (IN)']

filteredData = data.loc[(contactData['CONTACT'] == 1).values, cols]\
                   .rename(index={0:'Index'})
```

Notice we can *chain* methods such as `loc` and `rename` instead of explicitly assigning back to `filteredData` each time.

Answer (score 0):

can you try:

```
filteredData = stickData[contactData['CONTACT'] == 1].reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'Old_index')
```

or put this piece somewhere, i don't have your sample data, i can't test it out

```
.reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'Old_index')
```