# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str, when trying to do one one hot encoding with get_dummies

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, data-science, training-data

its not letting me one hot encode this column to make it in binary form, any idea why , dont understand the typerror. IT has worked perfectly in the past with the same data , not sure whats going on

```
<ipython-input-67-f853e47a6b2c> in <module>()
----> 1 dummies2=pd.get_dummies(x['call_type'])
      2 x=pd.concat([x,dummies2], axis=1)
      3 x

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

this is my dataset it was json but converted to csv

```
0   6/14/17 21:54   10 14TH ST\, San Diego\, CA 1151    2.0 32.705449   -117.151870
1   3/29/17 22:24   10 14TH ST\, San Diego\, CA 1016    2.0 32.705449   -117.151870
2   6/3/17 18:04    10 14TH ST\, San Diego\, CA 1016    2.0 32.705449   -117.151870
3   3/17/17 10:57   10 14TH ST\, San Diego\, CA 1151    2.0 32.705449   -117.151870
4   3/3/17 23:45    10 15TH ST\, San Diego\, CA 911P    2.0 32.705722   -117.150350
```

Comment: Is it possible you are using the old way of calling this? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html, does `pd.get_dummies(x, columns=['call_type'])` work? This provides the join  back to the data without you having to explicitly do that. i think maybe you are thinking of an older version of pandas when the way you show was how it was done.

Comment: how would integrate that with my code ? to added back to my x

Comment: Did you try it? There is no need to integrate it back, the function now returns the dummies joined with the original data.

Comment: @WoodyPride `['call_type', 'date_time', 'FullAddress', 'priority', 'day']` i only get this in return when i type in `pd.get_dummies(x, columns=['call_type'])
x`

Comment: are you sure? The function returns a view of the data, i.e it will not afftect the data you have. So you have to have `x=pd.read_csv('your_data.csv')` and then `x = pd.get_dummies(x, columns=['call_type'])` and now x will have all the columns you desire.

Comment: In other words you have to save the output of the function to a variable, it does not make changes to the data `inplace` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893457/python-pandas-understanding-inplace-true