# When i use the dropna function my dataframe turns into a "NoneType" object. why is this happening and how can I solve this issue

Tags: pandas, sorting, dataframe, nonetype

I am cleaning some data (its been a while) and when I drop the rows that have a nan within either of two specific columns I am left with a "noneType" object that I cannot run any further functions on. why is this happening and how do i fix this.

I expected this to drop rows that had nans in those columns but did not expect it to change to 'noneType'

`df = df.dropna(subset=['Step Age', 'Process Age'], inplace = True)`

Comment: Where is the Dataframe? Where is the code that actually calls `dropna`.  Please create a [mcve]

Comment: sorry! pasted wrong line of code just noticed that

Comment: df.dropna(subset=['Step Age', 'Process Age'], inplace = True)

Comment: Are you accidentally assigning the result back: `df = df.dropna(inplace=True)`? Inplace operations will return None.

Comment: I am. is the "df =" part unneccesary?

Comment: It's not just unnecessary, it's the problem. You either do `df = df.dropna(inplace=False)` or `df.dropna(inplace=True)` to modify `df`. (`inplace=False` is the default, so it suffices to just do `df = df.dropna()`, though I left it there to be explicit)

Comment: This question is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893457/python-pandas-understanding-inplace-true

Answer (score 1):

A dataframe cannot become a NoneType object.  Instead, various operations may empty the dataframe. In the question, the dataframe has been deallocated.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
from pandas.compat import StringIO

print(pd.__version__)

csvdata = StringIO("""Step Age,Process Age,Extra Col
,1,
1,,
,,""")

df = pd.read_csv(csvdata, sep=",")
df.dropna(subset=['Step Age', 'Process Age'], inplace = True)
print(df)
print(df.empty)
```

produces

```
0.24.2
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Step Age, Process Age, Extra Col]
Index: []
True
```