# How to fill Nan values for multiple columns at once?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, fillna

```
df
   Fruits  Veg       Non_veg
 1 Apple   Broccoli  Chicken
 2 Banana   Nan       Nan
 3  Nan    Tomato     Nan
```

In the above sample data frame, I have Nan values and I need to fill
it with forward filling all at once and the code I used is :

```
df[['Fruits','Veg','Non_veg']].fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True)
```

Is this way of coding is correct ? also if the forward filling cell has another Nan value like in the above data frame how to overcome?

The Expected output for ffill is:

```
df
       Fruits  Veg       Non_veg
     1 Apple   Broccoli  Chicken
     2 Banana  Broccoli  Chicken
     3 Banana  Tomato    Chicken
```

Comment: please show your expected output

Answer (score 1):

Use: [`DataFrame.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html).Here you can se how use **inplace** : [`How to use inplace=True`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893457/python-pandas-understanding-inplace-true)

```
#df.replace('Nan',np.nan) #if NaN is string
cols=['Fruits','Veg','Non_veg']
df[cols]=df[cols].ffill()
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `inplace` on slicing object. Do assigment

```
df.loc[:, ['Fruits','Veg','Non_veg']] = df.loc[:, ['Fruits','Veg','Non_veg']].ffill()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove `inplace=True` 
`df['Fruits','Veg','Non_veg'] = df['Fruits','Veg','Non_veg'].fillna(method= 'ffill')`