# Replacing values in a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to rename the `Weekday` to `day_of_week` in dataframe below

```
Weekday    Value
2          10
2          5
8          50
7          20
4          11
```

using

```
df = df.rename(columns = {'Weekday' : 'day_of_week'})
```

I then notice that `df` has been converted to `pandas.core.series.Series` from `DataFrame`, which is not what I meant, because I would like to replace all `8` with `1` in the column in a `DataFrame`, and I'm not sure how to do it with a `series`.

My question is:

1) what are the different ways of renaming a column in a pandas dataframe and the differences(regarding data type transformation)?

2) what is the best way to solve the problem in my case and how to do it?

Thanks

---

Update: 
Sorry the problem lies with replacing values `8` with `1` in column `day_of_week` after renaming.

New problem:
I used

```
df['day_of_week'].replace(['8'], '1') 
df['day_of_week'].describe()
```

and it showed that the values had not changed. What's the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Are you sure this is where your issue is? I have run the same and i get a df returned from rename not a pandas series

Comment: Yeah, works for me. No hidden conversion whatsoever.

Comment: That command looks fine to me. Could you check `type(df)` before running that command?

Comment: Another way to rename way could be: df.columns = ['day_of_week', 'Value'] but you have to specify all column names

Comment: @ChrisDoyle yeah it was a mistake- the problem actually lies with replacing the values. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: What is actually the problem then, I’m confused. There are seemingly two or three different questions in here.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I had some misunderstanding about what my actual problem was so the question was changed during the discussion. Sorry for the confusion. Problem is solved

Comment: @nilsinelabore In the end it’s just rename the columns + wrap all day numbers to 0-7?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the type and index of your dataframe at all times. The rename method applied to a dataframe always returns a dataframe.

```
df.index
type(df)
```

---

You could use:

```
#df=df.reset_index() # if Weekday is the index
df['Weekday']=df['Weekday'].mask(df['Weekday']>7,df['Weekday']%7)
df=df.rename(columns = {'Weekday' : 'day_of_week'})
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   day_of_week  Value
0            2     10
1            2      5
2            1     50
3            7     20
4            4     11
```

---

`Dataframe.rename` is what we use to rename the columns although you could use:

```
df.columns=[the names of your columns]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used `df['day_of_week'].replace(['8'], '1')` to replace values `8` with `1` but `df['day_of_week'].describe()` showed that the values didn't change. Could you please tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Could it be that your values ​​are not str?

Comment: add "inplace" option and make types in replace the same as in df: df['day_of_week'].replace(8, 1, inplace=True)

Comment: keep in mind that if it has a value like 9 or 10 or 23 you will have to include them in replace while the solution that I have budgeted does it always

Comment: `df['day_of_week']=df['day_of_week'].replace(['8'], '1')` or `df['day_of_week']=df['day_of_week'].replace([8], 1)`

Comment: Thank you. It worked:) May I ask what the difference is between `replace` and `inplace`?

Comment: inplace is an argument that is used so that the dataframe on which the methods apply is updated with the dataframe resulting from the methods applied. While replace is a method to replace dataframe values

Comment: normally instead of using for example `df.replace(8,1, inplace = True)` we use `df = df.replace(8,1)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893457/understanding-inplace-true

Comment: Is _`df['Weekday'].mask(df['Weekday']>7,df['Weekday']%7)`_ better than just `df['Weekday'].subtract(1).mod(7).add(1)`?