# How to divide a dataframe by a scalar value obtained from another dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a quick simple question. I have a dataframe such as this

```
  Column_4 Column_4
0     Data     Data
1   102832    79639
2    50034    21058
3    38230    18963
4    34503    14216
```

What I want to do is divide the values in each column by a scalar value that is derived from another dataframe, such as this.

```
          0         1
0  103000.0     500.0
```

So this is what I want to happen:

```
    Column_4           Column_4
0     Data               Data
1   102832/103000.0     79639/500.0
2    50034/103000.0     21058/500.0
3    38230/103000.0     18963/500.0
4    34503/103000.0     14216/500.0
```

I know you can divide a dataframe by scalar values, and even dataframes by values in other dataframes (by using the index to match them); however I have yet to find a way to divide a column of a dataframe by a scalar value that is obtained from another dataframe using pandas such as the above example.

Edit:
There was a string in my column (Data), so I have removed that. This is the new dataframe.

```
  Column_4 Column_4 
1   102832   79639   
2    50034   21058    
3    38230   18963   
4    34503   14216     
5    34219   11450
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one row in your second df:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"col1":["data",100,200,300,400],
                    "col2":["data",200,300,400,500]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[100],
                    "col2":[200]})

print (df1.iloc[1:].astype(int)/df2.values)

   col1  col2
0   1.0   1.0
1   2.0   1.5
2   3.0   2.0
3   4.0   2.5
```

Comment: When I try that I get this error: ValueError: Unable to coerce to DataFrame, shape must be (10, 4): given (1, 2) ......which is strange because you have a (4,2) and are dividing by a (1,2) in this example. So if it works for you it should work for me as well

Comment: I apologize, I had the setup incorrectly (the # of columns didn't match). With that corrected though, I get this error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'

Comment: Looking at your data again you seemed to have `data` as a string value in your columns. If so you need to skip that column. See edited above.

Comment: So I removed that row entirely. But I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Try `.astype(int)` before the division then, but i think you should probably go through your column for some cleanup first. There might be more strings in your column than you realize.

Comment: Does dataframe.drop actually remove the value from the dataframe? Or does it simply hide it? I notice my datatable starts from 1 now instead of zero (which would imply they're still there, just not visible anymore)

Comment: You need to specify whether you want to do it in place by calling `df.drop(...,inplace=True)` or through reassignment `df = df.drop(...)`.

Comment: In place simply replies with none. This is the line I used .drop([0],axis=0). Also using .astype(int) worked, but I simply don't understand why it didn't read my values as int

Comment: Like i said, you either do `inplace=True` which modifies your df in place and returns None, or assign it explicitly by `df = df.drop([0],axis=0).`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893457/understanding-inplace-true) is a good read on how inplace work.

Comment: I understand that, what I don't understand is why I need to put in .astype(int), when my values are integers and not strings.

Comment: `drop` returns a copy of the original df which had a `dtype` of `object` since you had string in it, so you need to coerce it into `int`.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the second data frame to list and do normal division (pandas will broadcast the division to each column)

```
# test data
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'c':[7], 'd':[8]})

#df1
#   a  b
#0  1  4
#1  2  5
#2  3  6

#df2
#   c  d
#0  7  8

res = df1[['a','b']]/df2.loc[0,['c','d']].tolist()

print(res)

#          a      b
#0  0.142857  0.500
#1  0.285714  0.625
#2  0.428571  0.750
```

Comment: Is there anyway to use pandas commands exclusively though (without having to convert my dataframe into a list)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[102832, 79639], [50034, 21058], [38230, 18963], [34503, 14216]], columns=['A', 'B'])
df1

    A       B
0   102832  79639
1   50034   21058
2   38230   18963
3   34503   14216
```

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[103000.0, 500.0]])
df2

           0        1
0   103000.0    500.0
```

Columns names need to be the same from both tables

```
df1 / pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df2.values, df1.shape[0], axis=0), columns=['A', 'B'])

    A           B
0   0.998369    159.278
1   0.485767    42.116
2   0.371165    37.926
3   0.334981    28.432
```

Comment: This provides me with this error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'

Comment: samman, the values of your first dataframe needs to be in numeric format. Try this: `df1.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')`

Comment: I used dataframe.drop to remove it, but I'm getting the same error

Comment: Can you see both columns with int64 types using this command? `df1.dtypes`

Comment: This is the output. Column_4    object
Column_4    object
dtype: object

Comment: so this is why is not working. Both columns needs a numeric format i.e. int64, float64, etc. Not object. Verify the command: `df1 = df1.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')` You need to set the variable df1 again

Answer (score 1):

With you data set, you need to do it like this:

```
df4['Column_4'][1:].astype(int) / df5['0'][0]                                                                                                                                        
Out[363]: 
1    0.998369
2    0.485767
3    0.371165
4    0.334981
```