# fillna doens't fill null values

Tags: python, pandas, null, fillna

I like to fill the null values in a column with a formel based on other columns:

```
data['datacqtr'].fillna(data['datadate'].dt.year.apply(str) + str('Q')+data['datadate'].dt.quarter.astype(str))
```

Can you see where the problem is with my Code? Because there are some nulll values after this code.

My Dataframe:

> datadate | datacqtr 
>   2002-02-28|2002Q1

Dataacqtr stands for the Quarter.
And sometimes I have datadate but no datacqtr (Quarter). So I like to fill up the colmn datacqtr based on the colmn datadate.

Comment: This is a pretty fundamental misunderstanding of the python language. You're not calling `fillna()`, you're reassigning it

Comment: Ugh, please make sure you actually post correct code. The only thing I can think of is that you haven't used `inplace=True`. You need to get these things correct with a [mcve] before posting... it's a single line of code, there's no real excuse to not get it correct

Comment: yes this is the solution. inplace=true is missing. Thank you

Comment: might be worth going through all the answers in the linked dupe , especially [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59242208/9840637)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inplace = true is missing. Got the solution.

Answer (score 1):

`fillna()` is a **method** on a dataframe -- you pass arguments to it. In the snippet above it looks like you are assigning something to it instead. It would help to get a sample of the dataframe you're working with and what your expected result is.