# Pandas - Add values from series to dataframe column based on index of series matching some value in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

**Data**

```
pb = {"mark_up_id":{"0":"123","1":"456","2":"789","3":"111","4":"222"},"mark_up":{"0":1.2987,"1":1.5625,"2":1.3698,"3":1.3333,"4":1.4589}}
data = {"id":{"0":"K69","1":"K70","2":"K71","3":"K72","4":"K73","5":"K74","6":"K75","7":"K79","8":"K86","9":"K100"},"cost":{"0":29.74,"1":9.42,"2":9.42,"3":9.42,"4":9.48,"5":9.48,"6":24.36,"7":5.16,"8":9.8,"9":3.28},"mark_up_id":{"0":"123","1":"456","2":"789","3":"111","4":"222","5":"333","6":"444","7":"555","8":"666","9":"777"}}
pb = pd.DataFrame(data=pb).set_index('mark_up_id')
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

**Expected Output**

```
test = df.join(pb, on='mark_up_id', how='left')
test['cost'].update(test['cost'] + test['mark_up'])
test.drop('mark_up',axis=1,inplace=True)
```

**Or..**

```
df['cost'].update(df['mark_up_id'].map(pb['mark_up']) + df['cost'])
```

**Question**

Is there a function that does the above, or is this the best way to go about this type of operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the second solution you propose or better this:

```
df['cost']=(df['mark_up_id'].map(pb['mark_up']) + df['cost']).fillna(df['cost'])
```

I think using update can be uncomfortable because it doesn't return anything.

Let's say [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) is more flexible.

We can also use [`DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) 
in order to continue working on the DataFrame that the assignment returns.

```
df.assign( Cost=(df['mark_up_id'].map(pb['mark_up']) + df['cost']).fillna(df['cost']) )
```

---

**Time comparision with `join` method**

```
%%timeit
df['cost']=(df['mark_up_id'].map(pb['mark_up']) + df['cost']).fillna(df['cost'])
#945 µs ± 46 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

---

```
%%timeit
test = df.join(pb, on='mark_up_id', how='left')
test['cost'].update(test['cost'] + test['mark_up'])
test.drop('mark_up',axis=1,inplace=True)
#3.59 ms ± 137 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**slow..**

---

```
%%timeit
df['cost'].update(df['mark_up_id'].map(pb['mark_up']) + df['cost'])
#985 µs ± 32.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Finally,I recommend you see: [`Underastanding inplace`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893457/understanding-inplace-true) and [`When I should use apply`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code)

Comment: Thanks! I guess i'm more so wondering if there is a clever use of functions like applymap etc that leverage lambda or if using join/map is the way to go

Comment: I think `join` is not necessary here. On the other hand you have to know that `DataFrame.apply` in general is not recommended to use it only when strictly necessary. I will update the solution with a link to the topic on applying SO