# Adding rows to a multi-indexed DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add/update rows to a Pandas DataFrame which is multi-indexed, and the question [Add one row to pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/add-one-row-to-pandas-dataframe/10716007#10716007)
does not seem to address this problem. For instance, the following:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x', 'y', 'z', 't'])
df.set_index(['x', 'y'])
df.loc[(1, 2), :] = [1, 3]
```

gives the error

```
KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([1, 2], dtype='int64')] are in the [index]"
```

By the way: is there a simpler way to initialize the DataFrame than the one above ? I tried

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['z', 't'], index=pd.MultiIndex(names=['x', 'y']))
```

but this gives the error

```
TypeError: Must pass both levels and codes
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use `df.set_index(['x', 'y'], inpace=True)`

Comment: Or `df = df.set_index(['x', 'y'])`

Comment: Thanks for this answer!

Comment: Just fyi, better use @jezrael second comment, `inplace` argument is not recommended by pandas devs: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59242208/4909087) of mine which links to a relevant GitHub issue