# Dataframe .where() method returns None

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, where-clause

I am trying to filter a dataframe by the values inside one of the columns. The dataframe has a `Gender` column. And I am trying to filter the values by fetching only the columns that have 'Female' in the `Gender` column.

When I filter using lambda:

```
df = df.loc[lambda x: x['Gender'] == 'Female']
```

I get the correct results, but I am required to use the `.where()` method. When I use the following line instead, I get zero results:

```
filter = df['Gender'] == 'Female'
df = df.where(filter, inplace = True)
```

Why is this?

Comment: Either do assignment without `inplace=True` or do `inplace=True` without assignment.

Comment: [don't use `inplace=True`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59242208/4909087).