# change specific columns name in one Go in Python

Tags: python, pandas

my dataframe-:

```
Unnamed: 0     AsF      demos   Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2  Unnamed: 3  Unnamed: 4
1               2        3        3            3           3          3    
2               3        4        6             6          6          6


Expected result-:

               AsF     demos    
1               2        3        3            3           3          3    
2               3        4        6             6          6          6

i tried 
df.rename( columns={'Unnamed: 0':'','Unnamed: 1':''}, inplace=True)
```

But I can't do that, because number of this kind of columns("unnamed:0") is not fix

I want to do this,because when i convert DF into CSV, it comes with "Unnamed" name that I do not want.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: So you want the columns to be nameless? That's not an option... How will pandas know which column to access?

Comment: @snatchysquid I want to set all "Unnamed: " to " " this

Comment: `pd.to_csv('file.csv', header=False)` - this writes csv without column header names. [Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas-dataframe-to-csv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, [`.rename()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)'s column param can also get a function, and not just a dict!

you can write a simple lambda to check the prefix of the column name, like this:

```py
df = df.rename(columns=lambda col: '' if col.startswith('Unnamed:') else col)
```

Comment: try and rid your self of the `inplace=True` and your golden [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59242208/9375102)

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
 df.columns = df.columns[0:2]+[''] * len(df.columns[2:]) 
 df.to_csv('filename.csv', header=False)
```

Comment: Thanks ,but those two columns will be removed!, I don't  want to do that

Comment: with header false columns are not removed what so ever. only header row will not be inserted. is uggest you check this documentation "https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html"

Comment: I meant to say this!! columns (names)(it will remove all column  names)