# What is the main purpose of have inplace= true in "df.dropna(subset = ["price"], axis = 0, inplace = true)"?

Tags: python

My question is about purpose of have inplace= true in "df.dropna(subset = ["price"], axis = 0, inplace = true)"?

Comment: so that it does the operations in place.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding inplace=True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893457/understanding-inplace-true)

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the 2 alternative code styles:

```
# 1
df.dropna(subset = ["price"], axis = 0, inplace = true)

# 2
df = df.dropna(subset = ["price"], axis = 0)
```

Choosing one is the matter of personal style, to me the latter one is more readable.