# Replace value in xlsx file using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have looked at other examples and implemented them, but I'm not getting the right results.
I have several dataframes that looks like this

```
Player_Name 

  0 J.T. Poston

Player_Name
  
  0 J.T. Poston
```

I'm trying to change the names to match another excel file I have so I don't have do it manually with excel index. Here is my code.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import os

year = 2018

path_to_excel = '/Users/aus10/Desktop/PGA/PGA_Tour_Stats/Tournament_Results_Excel/'+str(year)+''
excel_files = [pos_json for pos_json in os.listdir(path_to_excel) if pos_json.endswith('.xlsx')]

for files in excel_files:

    df = pd.read_excel('/Users/aus10/Desktop/PGA/PGA_Tour_Stats/Tournament_Results_Excel/'+str(year)+'/'+files+'')
    df['Player_Name'].replace(to_replace='J.T. Poston', value='JT Poston')
    print(df)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('/Users/aus10/Desktop/PGA/PGA_Tour_Stats/Tournament_Results_Excel/'+str(year)+'/'+files+'', engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
    df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'center'})
    pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 100)
    pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
    writer.save()
```

However, when I open up the excel file after running the code the name isn't changed. Is there something I'm missing or a specific way I need to do it because I'm using a `.xlsx` file instead of `.csv`?

Comment: I also tried ```df.replace(to_replace='J.T. Poston', value='JT Poston')``` but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important parameter in this case is `inplace`. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893457/understanding-inplace-true) or find the note on this topic directly in the documentation of [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html).

It should be enough for you to use this update:

```py
df['Player_Name'] = df['Player_Name'].replace(to_replace='J.T. Poston', value='JT Poston')
```

Otherwise you are doing replace on the copy, not the original dataframe.

Option with `inplace=True` should be valid as well:

```py
df.replace(to_replace='J.T. Poston', value='JT Poston', inplace=True)
```