# Save an updated dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, save

I am using pandas for the first time.

```py
df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//10).mean()
```

I used the code above which works to take an average of every 10th row. I want to save this updated data frame but doing `df.to_csv` is saving the original dataframe which I imported.

I also want to multiply one column from my `df` (`df.groupby` dataframe essentially) with a number and make a new column. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operation:
`df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//10).mean()`

Might return the averages dataframe as you want it, but it wont change the original dataframe. Instead you'll need to do:

`df_new = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//10).mean()`

You could assign it the same name if you want. The other options is some operations which you might expect to modify the dataframe accept in `inplace` argument which normally defaults to False. See [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893457/understanding-inplace-true).

To create a new column which is an existing column multpied by a number you'd do:

`df_new['new_col'] = df_new['existing_col']*a_number`