# Sort pandas dataframe by date or column

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, datetime

The solutions I have found in a similar question are not working for me. I have a pandas DataFrame including mock sales data. I want to sort by date since they are currently out of order. I have tried converting to a datetime object. I also tried creating a Month and Day column and sorting by them but that did not work either. Date is in `YYYY-MM-DD` format

Here is my solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
data = pd.read_csv(path)
# sort by date (not working)
data['OrderDate'] = pd.to_datetime(data['OrderDate'])
data.sort_values(by='OrderDate')
data.reset_index(inplace=True)
# sort by month then day (not working)
data.sort_values(by='Month')
data.sort_values(by='Day')
data.reset_index(inplace=True)
# export csv
data.to_csv(fileName, index=False)
```

Comment: you need to assign the dataframe back to a variable - and don't use [inplace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59242208/9375102) `data = data.sort_values(by='OrderDate',ascending=False/True)`

Comment: Ah silly mistake, that fixed the problem thank you