# How to drop the columns by using pandas.Series.str.contains

Tags: python, pandas

DataFrame like this:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'name':['test1','test2','test','D','E','F'],'sex':['man','woman','woman','man','woman','man']},index=['a','b','c','d','e','f'])
print(df)
print('*'*100)
```

I can drop the rows by index label:

```
df.drop(df[df.name.str.contains('test')|df.sex.str.contains('woman')].index,inplace=True)
print(df)
```

How can i find out the columns label which contains 'test' or 'woman' and remove the columns

Comment: ```df.drop(df[df.name.str.contains('test')|df.sex.str.contains('woman')],inplace=True, axis=1)```

Comment: @darthbaba `inplace` is not recommend anymore see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893457/understanding-inplace-true)

Comment: The result of your code shows the Empty DataFrame,but I just want to filter columns by criteria and drop the columns like column  'name' ,column 'sex' ,keep 'id' column in it

Comment: From what I can understand you need only those IDs which doesn't have 'test' in 'name' column and 'woman' in 'sex' column? Then ```df[~(df.name.str.contains('test')) & ~(df.sex.str.contains('woman'))]['id']``` will give you such IDs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a `bitwise` ampersand `&` for an AND condition and just re-assign the dataframe.

you can invert conditions with `~`

it's recommended not to use `inplace` anymore see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893457/understanding-inplace-true)

```
df1 = df[~(df['name'].str.contains('test')
                         ) & ~(df['sex'].str.contains('woman'))]


print(df1)

   id name  sex
d   4    D  man
f   6    F  man
```