# why 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'head'

Tags: python, nonetype

```
df_new=df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
print(df_new.head(10))
```

---

why does it shows AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'head'

Comment: If you use `inplace` then the operation is performed *in place*, meaning that it will not return anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding inplace=True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893457/understanding-inplace-true)

Answer (score 4):

`inplace=True` makes it directly modify the original dataframe.

So you would either not to that, like:

```
df_new = df.fillna(0)
print(df_new.head(10))
```

Or just keep it as `df`:

```
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
print(df.head(10))
```