# How to change values of a column (boolean) by other values?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to change the boolean values of my "success" column in my "members" dataframe. Specifically, I would like to change the True values to "success" and the False values to "fail". Would you know how to do this?

code :

```
import pandas as pd 
members = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-09-22/members.csv")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using replace as follow:

```py
members['success'].replace({True: 'success', False: "fail"}, inplace = True)
```

Remember, `inplace` applies the changes directly to the DataFrame

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done by using pandas [replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html). Careful it is different from python's built-in replace [.str.replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html).

```
members['success'].replace({False:"fail",True:"success"},inplace=True)
```

Based on Corralien's comment and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59242208/11897007) answer addressing the use of inplace, perhaps it would be better to redefine the series:

```
members['success'] = members['success'].replace({False:"fail",True:"success"})
```

Comment: I prefer this version: `members = members.replace({'success': {False:"fail",True:"success"}})`. I don't like the argument `inplace=True` :)

Comment: Thank you Corralien, I will update my answer to show this, because you are right, it is better to avoid the use of inplace.