# This pandas series is a view... into what?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following example.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "x": [1, 2, 3],
    "y": [4, 5, 6]
})

x = df["x"]
df.drop(index=[0], inplace=True)
```

Now we have `x._is_view` is `True`, so I would expect `x` to be a "view" into `df`. In other words, I would expect `x` to be identical to `df["x"]`.
However, `x` still contains the values `[1, 2, 3]`, while `df["x"]` only contains the values `[2, 3]`.
In what sense is `x` a view?

P.S. In my head, I have been imagining that `df.drop(..., inplace=True)` is literally dropping rows of `df` from memory. Perhaps this is not the case...

Comment: If you change the second-to-last line to `x = df` it would have the behavior you are expecting.  But if you want to see really weird behavior, leave that line as-is and change the last line to `df["x"].drop(index=[0], inplace=True)`.  Then you would have `x = [2,3]` and `df["x"] = [1,2,3]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inplace` does not guarantee that the dataframe will be modified in place. In this case, as in many cases, it creates a copy and reassigns it to `df`. See the discussion of `inplace` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893457/understanding-inplace-true-in-pandas).

As for `x` being a view, if you execute `x.values.base` you will get:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Thus, `x` is a view of the original dataframe, which is not assigned to `df` anymore.

Here is another way to verify it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "x": [1, 2, 3],
    "y": [4, 5, 6]
})
df_arr = df.values # numpy array underlying df
x = df["x"]
df.drop(index=[0], inplace=True)
```

Now if you run

```
np.shares_memory(df_arr, x.values)
```

the result is `True`, since `x` occupies the same space in the memory as `df` originally did. On the other hand

```
np.shares_memory(df_arr, df.values)
```

returns `False`, because values of `df` now reside somewhere else.

Comment: it's stuff like this that will cause pandas to become used less and less.  When a data frame gets passed to a function, for example, it can become highly confusing whether the original df is being modified, or new data is being created.

Comment: @ekrall In case you haven't read it.

https://wesmckinney.com/blog/apache-arrow-pandas-internals/

Comment: @MichaelGardner I hadn't read that before; thanks.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me about `values.base`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the previous answer.  `inplace` does not guarantee it won't be copied.  You can inspect the unique id of each object to proof it out.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "x": [1, 2, 3],
    "y": [4, 5, 6]
})

x = df

print(f'Original: {id(df)}')
print(f'View:     {id(x)}')
print(f'Copy:     {id(df.drop(index=[0], inplace=True))}')

Out[1]
Original: 2570551559120
View:     2570551559120
Copy:     140708949432448
```

Comment: Thank you for teaching me about `id`.