# Is there a best or recommended practice for naming dataframes while modifying them?

Tags: python, pandas

It does not always make sense and I've additionally learned from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893457/understanding-inplace-true-in-pandas/59242208#59242208) to not use inplace=True in pandas. As a result, my code often looks like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv("path_to_file.csv")
df1 = df.drop(columns_to_be_deleted, axis = "columns")
df2 = df1.apply(lambda x: my_own_function(x), axis = 1)
...
df6 = df5.apply(lambda x: my_other_function(x), axis = 1)
```

This especially leads to problems when I try and insert a new modification later on ("df_1_a", "df_1_b"). A way to prevent this is labeling the dataframes more meaningful like "df_applied_f1". However, this approach becomes annoying when working a lot with the long name.

Are there any best practices available how to deal with this problem?

Comment: Unless you need to reference each of these dataframes you might find it easier to just overwrite `df`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to reference some of these dataframes

Answer (score 3):

You can use a pipeline. This way no need to use intermediate variables.

A handy side effect is that you can also easily comment one or more steps if needed (assuming your code tolerates to skip this/these step(s))

```
df = (pd.read_csv("path_to_file.csv")
        .drop(columns_to_be_deleted, axis = "columns")
        .apply(lambda x: my_own_function(x), axis = 1)
       # ...
        .apply(lambda x: my_other_function(x), axis = 1)
     )
```

Comment: Thanks, looks very clean! However, I sometimes want to access a certain version of the df within the pipeline.