# How to drop all values that are 0 in a single column pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

1. I have a pandas DataFrame that was created from some raw data, there are hundreds of lines so I will just show the first 10 rows.
2. ```
          text

    0       0
    1       0
    2       0
    3       0
    4  26.529
    5       0
    6  25.558
    7       0
    8       0
    9       0
   ```
3. I want to get rid of all the zeros in my data frame and replace the column name from 'text' to 'Results', so the final data should look like this:
4. ```
         Results

    0    26.529
    1    25.558
   ```
5. My method was to use the df.drop() method to drop all rows containing zeros. My code looks like this:

   ```
    df = df.drop(df[df['text'] == 0].index,inplace=True)

    # I didn't write the code to replace to column name yet
   ```
6. Somehow when I run this, the resulting df is empty/ nonetype. I have no idea why the drop method just dropped everything in my dataframe. Please help! Much appreciated in advance!
7. When I debug the code in debug mode (vs code), I see the values in my df are as follows:

   ```
    I noticed that every element in my df is an object type. I want to get rid of all the arrays with an empty object. Ex. "000:array([''],dtype=object)"


    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yk63P.png
   ```

Comment: Btw, the index values shown on the left are not actual values in the data frame.

Comment: You don't need to `df.drop()`, just use boolean masking itself: `df = df[df["text"] != 0]`

Comment: Hi, I added a screenshot of the variable in my df above. You can copy and paste the image link into your browser to see what I got. Thanks.

Comment: The reason you're getting an empty dataframe is because you're assigning an in-place operation. You can only *either* use `inplace=True` OR reassign the result via `df = ...`. You cannot do both, because when `inplace=True`, the operation modifies the original data and returns `None` (think of trying to do `my_list = my_list.append(3)`), which you are then assigning to `df`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893457/understanding-inplace-true-in-pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with the following

`df[df["text"].str.strip()!="0"].rename(columns={'text':'Results'}).reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work for me. I tried and the results still contain zeros.

Comment: What is the output when you run `df["text"].dtype`. I suspect there could be spaces around the 0's?

Comment: They are objects. For example, when I ran in debugger mode with setting a breakpoint after the df was created. I can see in the df variables contains something like this "000:array([''],dtype=object".

Comment: Hi, I added a screenshot of the variable in my df above. You can copy and paste the image link into your browser to see what I got. Thanks.

Comment: I edited my answer to strip spaces, let me know how it goes

Comment: Hi, I just tried. Unfortunately, the results are still the same. Zeros are still in the df.

Comment: Im not sure what else it could be.. Is this a public dataset I can access? If not, I dont have any more ideas :(

Comment: This is not a public dataset. But I added a link to the snapshot of the variables in my df above. Did you get a chance to see it? It might help.

Comment: Yes I did. It is tough to get a sense of what is wrong from that image. Are the rows with empty strings those that have 0 in them?

Comment: Yes, those rows turn out to be zeros. Could it be that they are object datatypes so they can't be dropped or stripped? Or maybe my df wasn't properly created.

Comment: Could be.. Maybe try filtering based on empty strings as well. Something like `df[df["text"]!=""]`

Comment: Hi, here's a link of the context of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71162678/how-to-properly-extract-information-from-bounded-regions-from-images-using-openc

Comment: Hi, df[df["text"]!=""] didn't work either. What a stubborn df that I have created lol!

Comment: Its never easy lol. Good luck my freind!

Comment: Thanks, I will update my post if I find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this problem:

First I converted the data type from object to float64 in my df:

```
    df['text'] = pd.to_numeric(df['text'])
```

Then I proceeded to drop the 'nan' values from the df using:

```
    df = df.dropna()
```

This works for me!