# Remove row when the row already exist by two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem. I want to remove all rows where `customerId` and `fromDate` have the same value. For example. The row `1` and `4` are the same. So row `4` should be removed. But how could I find the row what is the same?

Dataframe

```py
   customerId    fromDate
0           1  2021-02-22
1           1  2021-03-18
2           1  2021-03-22
3           1        None
4           1  2021-03-18
5           3  2021-02-22
6           3  2021-02-22
```

Code

```py
import pandas as pd


d = {'customerId': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3],
     'fromDate': ['2021-02-22', '2021-03-18', '2021-03-22', None, '2021-03-18', '2021-02-22', '2021-02-22']
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)
```

What I want

```py
   customerId    fromDate
0           1  2021-02-22
1           1  2021-03-18
2           1  2021-03-22
3           1        None
5           3  2021-02-22

# Removed
# 4           1  2021-03-18
# 6           3  2021-02-22
```

Comment: You can use df.drop_duplicates() to remove duplicated rows.

Comment: @shakiba.mrd thank you. I was not beware of this command, sorry! :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
df.drop_duplicates()
```

Which drop all the duplicate rows
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Answer (score 0):

IIUC You can use drop_duplicates to remove duplicates

```
df.drop_duplicates(inplace = True)
```

Comment: see the [second answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893457/understanding-inplace-true-in-pandas) using `inplace=True` is considered harmful.

Comment: So if I understood the post correctly the answer should simply be df = df.drop_duplicates()

Comment: exactly - `inplace` I'm sure will go away in the future, or at least come with a bigger warning sign.

Comment: Thats great info thank you for letting me know, I'll stop using it in my coding going forward!