# inplace = True not working along "\ " new character

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, split, line-breaks, drop

Trying to run a code in the jupyter notebook:

```
location.str.split("\n",expand=True)\
.drop(columns = 1, inplace = True)
```

but failing to get the desired result. Nothing is happennig, not even the error is popping up.

Whereas, the below code is giving me the desired result:

```
location = location.str.split("\n",expand=True)\
.drop(columns = 1)
```

Just want to know the issue!

Just for the reference -

Location used to be a list. Later got converted into a Series. Got splited up using str.split().

if I'm using the code in different code blocks, then it is working fine -

```
location.str.split("\n",expand=True)
```

```
location.drop(columns = 1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Here `drop(inplace=True)` applies to a temporary dataframe that is not accessible in the following code. Using `inplace=True` makes sense only when you apply a method to a pandas object you have a handle to access it in the following code.

Answer (score 2):

The expression`location.str.split("\n",expand=True)\ .drop(columns = 1, inplace = True)` in fact do not return value, because the parameter `inplace` is set to `True`. If you remove `inplace=True` or set `inplace=False`, then it returns value, which could be what you want.

Comment: For more information about `inplace` parameter, you can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893457/understanding-inplace-true-in-pandas?rq=1). Hope it will help.

Comment: inplace=True is not even making changes to the original dataframe. The whole is being avoided by the compiler.