# How to save the changes after a loop in python?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-analysis, data-cleaning

`for i in data['test preparation course']: if i == 'none': i = None`

here, I'm trying to convert 'none' string with None values in python, and it went well.

I just want to activate the changes on the dataset

Comment: Assigning to `i` does not change `data`; it just makes the name `i` refer to somethign else. If you want to change what `data['...']` refers to, you need to assign directly to `data['...']`. (Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.)

Comment: using a loop in pandas is an anti pattern . Can you tell us what you're trying to do and we perhaps help you more.

Comment: I'm just trying to convert "none" as a string to None Python object (like: np.nan or something like that)

Answer (score 2):

Instead, use [`pandas.Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) function:

```
data['test preparation course'].replace('none', None, inplace=True)
```

Comment: don't use [`inplace =True`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59242208/9375102)

Comment: @ScottBoston the linked post has more info - tldr, no performance gains, and does not stop and does not stop copies of your dataframe from being created.